# What wrong with this code: first appearance of a word

Tags: python, algorithm

I wrote a program (appear) that keeps generating random letters, from a to z, till a given word appears:

```
import random

def appear(word):
    word = list(word)
    w = word
    l = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    i = 0

    while len(w) > 0:
        r = int(random.random() * 26)
        print(l[r], end='')

        if (w[0] == l[r] and i == 1) or (w[0] == l[r] and len(w) == len(word)):
            i = 1
            del w[0]
        else:
            i = 0
            w = word
```

For example, appear('car') should produce: ajzkcar.

I tried printing in each loop the value of w, and the problem seems to be that the program fails to reset w to the original word if it doesn't find two consecutive letters, even though I clearly say that it should in the last "else"

Comment: That is about mutability of lists in python. If you delete the first element of list w, it also does it from the original list word. You need to do a hard copy w=word.copy() or use copy.deepcopy()

Comment: Hi! Did you end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the letters that you have generated in memory, and compare them with the letters of the target word.

The word you're looking for has a fixed length. When you generate a new letter, you need to add that new letter to your memory at the right, and discard the oldest letter from your memory, at the left.

What data structure to use for this? Adding letters to the right and removing letters from the left, so that the total length remains fixed? I immediately think about a **fixed-length queue**.

The simplest way to get a fixed-length queue in python is to use `collections.deque` with a `maxlen` argument.

Also, to choose a letter, I have a preference for `random.choice(letters)` over `letters[int(random.random() * 26)]`

```py
from collections import deque
from random import choice, choices
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

def appear(word):
    queue = deque(choices(alphabet, k=len(word)), maxlen=len(word))
    target = deque(word)
    print(''.join(queue), end='')
    while queue != target:
        new_letter = choice(alphabet)
        queue.append(new_letter)
        print(new_letter, end='')

appear('a')
# jca

appear('ab')
# zdoxkcnswafzsclmeduwhyhpdfwljujduwvbsxayihtfmlqrjxamlqnestzsncjjzbyfuzaczmuaiddfehckkrcnzfwwgnxfxcaifasaybokkxrqievmwqhisnaqhezcxwxfrstvuvwoedstpsrxkmxbubab
```